# Hide/show hidden divs

Tags: javascript, html

I made this script to hide and show divs but I want to add an extra div / radio. Before the extra div was added all was fine now the system won't work. `cpcdata` is the new div which I added.

This is the HTML:

```
   <div>
                Performance Goal</label>
            </div>


                <label id="per1">
                <input name="performance" type="radio" checked="checked" 
value="43"> No Goal</label>

                <label id="per2">
                <input name="performance" type="radio" value="43"> 
CTR</label>

                <label id="per3">
                <input name="performance" type="radio" value="43"> 
CPA</label>

                <label id="per4">
                <input name="performance" type="radio" value="43"> 
CPC</label>

        </div>
    </div><br>
    <br>

    <div id="ctrdata">
        CTR DATA to collect
    </div>

    <div id="cpadata">
       CPA DATA to collect
    </div>

    <div id="cpcdata">
       CPC DATA to collect
    </div>
```

Here is the JS used so far:

```
<script>

$("#ctrdata").hide();
$("#cpadata").hide();
$("#cpcdata").hide();
$(".form-group input[type='radio']").on("change", function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "per3"){
        $("#ctrdata").hide();
        $("#cpadata").show();
    }else if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "per2"){
        $("#ctrdata").show();
        $("#cpadata").hide();
    }else{
        $("#ctrdata").hide();
        $("#cpadata").hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: question is how to modify the js - I could make it work with the 3 radios / divs .... but not with the 4 - confused as to the correct way to add / modify the js

Comment: Try and get some decent formatting with that code. It will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling show() on the new div you added. You can also simplify the function by hiding everything on change, then just showing the div you want to see.

```
<script>
function hide_divs() {
    $("#ctrdata").hide();
    $("#cpadata").hide();
    $("#cpcdata").hide();
}
hide_divs();
$(".form-group input[type='radio']").on("change", function (e) {
    hide_divs();
    if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "per3"){
        $("#cpadata").show();
    }else if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "per2"){
        $("#ctrdata").show();
    }else{
        $("#cpcdata").show();
    }
}); </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that I see what you mean - tried this code, it works well but all the divs are visible on page load - the aim is to have none visible

Comment: @Brian I edited to answer to hide all divs on page load

Comment: much appreciated - seems to fixx that issue but  now when returning to the 'no target' option - the CPC div appears - I tried adding and extra hide after the show - but not work

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this with data-attributes and :checked. Here is one way that should do the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5kwdtn08/

```js
// cache the nodes you'll be working with
var $inputs = $('.myForm').find('input');
var $data = $('.data');

// hide the view area to start
$data.hide();

// set click handler to find the clicked input's value + use that value to show the associated view area
$inputs.on('change', function() { // click or 'change' are probably the same in this case...
  $data.hide();
  var dataType = $(this).val();
  $('.' + dataType).show(); // or you could add a class of 'active' with display block etc.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='' class='myForm'>

  <label class='input-w radio'>
    <input type='radio' name='performance' checked='checked' value='0' />
    <span class='label'>No Goal</span>
  </label>

  <label class='input-w radio'>
    <input type='radio' name='performance' value='ctr' />
    <span class='label'>CTR</span>
  </label>

  <label class='input-w radio'>
    <input type='radio' name='performance' value='cpa' />
    <span class='label'>CPA</span>
  </label>

  <label class='input-w radio'>
    <input type='radio' name='performance' value='cpc' />
    <span class='label'>CPC</span>
  </label>

</form>


<div class='data ctr'>
  CTR DATA to collect
</div>

<div class='data cpa'>
  CPA DATA to collect
</div>

<div class='data cpc'>
  CPC DATA to collect
</div>
```

If your form - or *not form* gets more complex - and has many of these / you'll need to target their specific groups/sections etc. - here is a more detailed example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bgxq4vve/

Comment: Thanks a million - seems to work well - only question is - this will be part of a wider form (transfering to a db) is there anyway to run with out the myForm call ? hope you understand what I mean

Comment: I don't understand. Yes, there are ways to amend this to fit any situation.

Comment: Yes - thought my comment was not clear - sorry!
as I look at it - the way were are is that the form is self contained ....
but the final page will have several other form elements ... 
I guess I could extend the form you provided to cover them all - if I changed the form name and changed the reffernce in the script to match, would this be a problem?

Comment: That's how you do it. 'Query' the elements you need and 'do' the stuff.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work well - I guess the real test will come whn I try to edit it some more! Many thanks - this has solved my problem at the moment.

Comment: No matter how you choose to use this, make sure you understand what the code is doing, and you'll be able to reason about whatever you make. This doesn't answer all future questions - just this one.

Comment: Wise words indeed - I have tried putting several of the radio buttons + the hidden divs in a stack one above the other .... they are seperate option selections

but they interfere with each other - I thought that this might be due to the myForm name, so I tried renaming each section - but makes no difference - in isoslation, it all works just fine. Any sugestion as to what i am doing wrong? Clearly not got a full grip on the code as of yet!

Comment: That is another question - but here is an example of how I would go about it. My posted answer - answers your initial questions: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bgxq4vve/